# Behavior of GraphAssortativity

Tags: graphs-and-networks, correlation

My understanding is that `GraphAssortativity[g]` measures how commonly nodes in graph `g` connect to other nodes of similar degree. Based on that understanding, I would expect `GraphAssortativity[RandomGraph[WattsStrogatzDistribution[10,0]]]` to return 1, since the graph is a ring lattice where every node is connected to an equal number of neighbors. Instead it returns 0. Can anyone help me understand this behavior?

Comment: You may take a look to the paper "Assortativity in Complex Networks."